# Timezone drama for events calendar

Tags: datetime, events, timezone

Working on site where there is events calendar of conferences and webinars. Users are (literally) all over the world. Trying to figure out how I am going to handle time zones. Factors:
- Fields I am using are two Date/time fields for start and end time + one lightswitch for all day events
- Content editors will inevitably want to input dates for where they are happening. If the conference is in Paris at 9am they want it to show Paris 9am no mater where website user is in world
- For webinars, they have opposite issue. They want the time shown to be relative to user's timezone.
- Users can download ICS link

Has anyone developed a solution to this that works for users and content editors?